# Bewildering D3 behaviour - can't select text after zooming on map visualisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, maps

I've been working on making a map related visualisation in D3 for a site that for historical reasons is stuck using some old versions of jQuery, and I've come across a weird bug when implementing drag behaviour on the map.

I've extracted the D3 code, and put it onto a [gist listed below](http://bl.ocks.org/mrchrisadams/89d053977513e6042adf), and been able to replicate the strange behaviour, which you can trigger by:

1. Try loading the page below
2. Clicking on  a country
3. Trying to select some text

I can't seem to select text after I've zoomed into a country, and I suspect it's down to line 130 in the [d3_map.js file](https://gist.github.com/mrchrisadams/89d053977513e6042adf#file-d3_map-js-L132)

#### The problem gist

The gist is here:
https://gist.github.com/mrchrisadams/89d053977513e6042adf

The rendered gist on http://bl.ocks.org, is here:

http://bl.ocks.org/mrchrisadams/89d053977513e6042adf

#### On the strange mismatch of javascript libraries

It's strange to see such an old version of jQuery, I know. I'm unable to change it without breaking other functinality on the site, which is why we're stuck with the old library.

#### Why is this happening, and how do I reinstate normal text selection again?

I'm utterly stumped as to why triggering a zoom knocks out the ability to select text, and I'd welcome any pointers, because I'm somewhat at a loss now.

Oh well, fingers crossed...